# XNA Library DrawPrimitives throwing primitiveCount error

Tags: silverlight, xna

posted this on gamedev already but there wasn't much response so I'd like to try posting it here.

I downloaded the project from here http://silverlight.bayprince.com/tutorials.php?tutorial=13 and tried adding a new OBJ file with a few thousand vertices listed.

The classic teapot works but when I tried loading a different model with alot more vertices included, it suddenly throws this primitiveCount error when the DrawPrimitives gets called.

The code includes a class that would read the data from the OBJ file. This will then return a `VertexBuffer` object back to the main program. The drawing starts when the Draw event is called.

There are 417936 vertices created from the OBJ file and since I'm using a trianglelist, I divided the vertices by 3 to get the total primitives count.

here's the code for the draw event:

```
private void DrawingSurface_Draw(object sender, DrawEventArgs e)
        {
            GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsDeviceManager.Current.GraphicsDevice;

            device.Clear(ClearOptions.Target | ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color(0, 0, 0, 0), 10.0f, 0);

            device.RasterizerState = new RasterizerState()
            {
                CullMode = CullMode.None
            };

            device.SetVertexBuffer(_vertexBuffer);

            foreach (EffectPass pass in _effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {

                    pass.Apply();
                    device.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearClamp;
                    device.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, _vertexBuffer.VertexCount / 3);
            }

            // set camera
            _effect.World = Matrix.Identity;
            _effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(_x, _y, _z), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
            _effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, 2.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);

            // move camera along a circumference
            _x = (float)(_radius * Math.Sin(_hAngle * (Math.PI / 180)));
            _z = (float)(_radius * Math.Cos(_hAngle * (Math.PI / 180)));

            e.InvalidateSurface();
        }
```

then the error occurs on the DrawPrimitives.

Any clues about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think DrawPrimitives has a primitive or vertex limit at 65k...

Change the code to draw blocks of primitives...

```
      var start_vertex = 0;
      var part_count = 3 * 20000;
      var total_count = _vertexBuffer.VertexCount;
      while (total_count>0)
      {
          var count = Math.Min(total_count, part_count);
          device.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, start_vertex, count / 3); 
          total_count -= count;
          start_vertex += count;
      }
```

You can play with "part_count" size to find the limit.